# Equality of sum of squares of random variables related linearly

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

If $X\sim \mathscr N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random i.i.d sample from $X$. Define
\begin{align}
Y_1 &= \frac {1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\\
Y_2 &= \frac {1}{\sqrt {2\mathrm x1}} (X_1 - X_2)\\
Y_3 &= \frac {1}{\sqrt {3\mathrm x2}} (X_1 + X_2 - 2X_3)\\[0.2cm]\vdots\\ 
Y_n &= \frac {1}{\sqrt {n\mathrm x(n-1)}} (X_1 + X_2 + \cdots +X_{n-1} - (n-1)X_{n})\end{align}

We can show that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2$.

Hence using this above result and the joint distribution of $Y$ prove that

$ \bar{X} = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $S^2 = \frac 1{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ are independently distributed.

Comment: The probability distribution does not appear to be relevant to the question. $\qquad$

Comment: If someone has answered your earlier question and you change the question, kindly leave a remark that you edited the question.